# Nuget The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding char

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

Good Day, My VS2017 can connect to the web i tried that and updated the package source to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json and I am still having the same problem and yes I did go to all the info in Stack overflow nothing helps. I even install VS2015 and I am having the same problem

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What did you do then you got this error?

Comment: First tried re-installing VS 2017 that didn't help, changed the package source to several sources I thought VS not accessing the internet was the problem but  I can browse the internet within VS, and when I click on show errors got that error

Comment: Thanks for your replay. According to the error message, it seems that there is a syntax error in the `nuget.config` file, please try to close Visual Studio instance, then delete the `nuget.config` file in the path `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config`. Reopen the Visual Studio, nuget will re-generate it.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Thank you how do mark this as answered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Nuget The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding char

According to the error message, it seems that there is a syntax error in the `nuget.config` file.

So, to resolve this issue, please try to close all Visual Studio instance, delete the `nuget.config` file in the path `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config`. Then reopen the Visual Studio, Visual Studio/nuget will regenerate it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked for me using dotnet core 5, visual studio code 1.64.2 on windows 10 Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042